# glide Failed to load resource but success after refresh

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

glide failed to load resources with size 500kb above. but after I refresh the adapter, the image is successfully loaded.

glide

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(Server.storage +productsDataList.get(position).getPhoto().getPhoto_path())
                .centerCrop()
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Error loading image", e);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.productsImage);
```

log

```
W/Glide: Load failed for http://192.168.1.5:8000/storage/riceFieldPhotos/20-dHVLUpfRVp7acZHOkgJy.png with size [1334x910]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
E/TAG: Error loading image
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

i have add in my AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

i've tried using a recursive function, it worked but it was thrown an error after the third function call.

is there any other way for the image to load successfully?

Comment: Does your photo gets immediately available? It has happened to me in past. The Glide call was so fast that the server did not have the pic yet.

Comment: then how do you handle it?

Comment: As you said Recursion is one way. Reload the image on failing, but load it after some delay. You can use an Handler for that. Like I have a function called `loadImage()` which takes in a Boolean of `reload`. So if it is true and if there is a failure, I call the function again after some delay but this time send `reload` as false so it does not get stuck.

Comment: how many minutes delay?

Comment: How much ever it suits you. For me 2 seconds was enough. You know your server better

Comment: I ended up using a "weak handler". i know "weak handler" about 5 hours ago but don't want to try it because i don't want to add any more library in my project.
then actually I'm studying, so let me ask
what is the function return true or false in onLoadFailed and onResourceReady?
and may i see a sample code how do you use glide?

Comment: I code in Kotlin. If you want I can add a sample as an answer. Would you be able to translate it back to Java?

Comment: sure, someday i might have to use kotlin too